# How to apply SetSupportActionBar or onbackpress button on my toolbar using compound view

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

Im using compound view for toolbar which extends Relative Layout and can reuse with another activity, i would like to set the back button using SetSupportActionBar or backpress button on that toolbar but the view cannot enable setsupportactionbar, how to solve it?

```
public class ToolbarHeader : RelativeLayout
    {
    private ImageView ImgHome;
    private ImageView ImgProfile;
    private Toolbar TbHeader;
    private LinearLayout RlProfile;
    private TextView tvTitle;
    Context context;
    Activity activity = null;

    public ToolbarHeader(Context context, IAttributeSet attrs) : base(context, attrs)
    {
        Initialize(context);
        ImgHome.Click += (sender, e) =>
        {
          //apply back button here//
        };

    }

    public ToolbarHeader(Context context, IAttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) : base(context, attrs, defStyle)
    {
        Initialize(context);
    }

    private void Initialize(Context context)
    {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.GetSystemService(Context.LayoutInflaterService);
        inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.Toolbar_header, this);

        AssignUiElements();
        AssignClickHandlers();
    }

    private void AssignUiElements()
    {
        TbHeader = (Toolbar)FindViewById(Resource.Id.edit_toolbar);
        ImgHome = (ImageView)FindViewById(Resource.Id.img_home);
        RlProfile = (LinearLayout)FindViewById(Resource.Id.layout_profile);
        tvTitle = (TextView)FindViewById(Resource.Id.tv_title);

    }


    private void AssignClickHandlers()
    {

    }


}
```

The expected result, the back button will go to previous page and cancel the current page.

Comment: ya, its work, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could do like this:

in your activity `OnCreate()` method :

```
 protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);        
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.layout1);
        View toolBar = new ToolBarHeader(this);
        SupportActionBar.SetCustomView(toolBar, new Android.Support.V7.App.ActionBar.LayoutParams(Android.Support.V7.App.ActionBar.LayoutParams.MatchParent,Android.Support.V7.App.ActionBar.LayoutParams.MatchParent));
        SupportActionBar.SetDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
        ((Android.Support.V7.Widget.Toolbar)SupportActionBar.CustomView.Parent).SetContentInsetsAbsolute(0, 0);
    }
```

and  in your `ToolBarHeader.cs` add :

```
 ImgHome.Click += (sender, e) =>
    {
       ((Activity)context).Finish();
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

Actionbar is sort of a basic toolbar provided by default to be used on ACTIVITIES. Hence it won't work on a custom layout toolbar.

What you can do is create a static object which tracks the activities in a linked list
and then create your back button on the layout to go through the list and go back to the last activity. [LINKED LIST IN C#](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/linked-list-implementation-in-c-sharp/)

I don't know if xamarin supports Fragments and navigation, but if it does you can easily set up navigation within your app without extra work